# How old is Peter Weyland in Prometheus?

Tags: character, prometheus

In movie, Prometheus, Peter Weyland is very very old and he can only walk around with the help of an exoskeleton.

I would imagine Peter Weyland has all the money and resource to extend his life as much as possible.

Does anyone know how old he is? It is very interesting to see how cold he is when he is talking to his daughter who is also on board with Prometheus. Normally with a very old father and relatively young daughter, their relationship is closer.

Comment: While his relationship to his daught is certainly interesting, it really has *nothing* to do with his age and you using it as an overgeneralized argument against his age detracts from the actual question a little and makes seem somewhat like an XY problem.

Comment: Depending on a poster’s personal background, the opposite can also be argued. A very old father who married a much younger mother might look upon the birth of their child with more detachment than the births of his previous children earlier in his life. After all, the younger mother herself might be looked at as a “trophy wife” and not as a marriage of love. The new child could just be an inconvenience born at an age when patience has worn thin. Older people tend to treat their grandchildren differently than their children regardless of age. They expect more from their children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Villains Wiki](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Weyland) (sigh),

> Peter Weyland was born on October 1, 1990

So by 2093 (when the ship arrives in the orbit around LV-223) he is 103 years old.

His attitude towards his daughter has nothing to do with his age specifically; he's shown to be an arrogant / selfish individual seeking only immortality for himself. That's just his attitude with *everyone*.